# treatment of mouse events opencv gui vs pyqt

Tags: python, opencv, mouseevent, pyqt4

I was working with OpenCV gui functions for a while, and the possibilities are a little restricting for python users. Today I started with Pyqt and come across the following conclusion: qt is really confusing.

Now the question concerning mouse events:

In OpenCV I just do the following:

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow('Window',1)
def CallBackFunc(event,x,y,flags,param):
   global xc,yc,evt,flg
   xc,yc,evt,flg=x,y,event,flags

cv2.setMouseCallback('Window', CallBackFunc)
```

This opens a seperate thread, which constantly refreshes the global variables `xc,yc,evt,flg`, and I can access them anywhere, at anytime I want. If I want to stop the refreshing, I just do a `cv2.setMouseCallback('Window',nothing)`, whereby `nothing` is

```
def nothing():
  pass
```

It may not be the most beautiful way of dealing with mouse events, but I am fine with it. How can I achieve such freedom with PyQt?

EDIT:

For example, the following script is displaying a white circle, and constantly drawing a text into it.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
import numpy as np 
import cv2

class QCustomLabel (QtGui.QLabel):


    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)


    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.x,self.y=eventQMouseEvent.x(),eventQMouseEvent.y()
        cvImg=np.zeros((900,900),dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.circle(cvImg,(449,449),100,255,-1)
        cv2.putText(cvImg,"x at {}, y at {}".format(self.x,self.y),(375,455), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5,(0,0,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
        height, width= cvImg.shape
        bytearr=cvImg.data
        qImg = QtGui.QImage(bytearr, width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))

    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        self.evt=eventQMouseEvent.button()


class QCustomWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowOpacity(1)
        # Init QLabel
        self.positionQLabel = QCustomLabel(self)
        # Init QLayout
        layoutQHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layoutQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.positionQLabel)

        self.setLayout(layoutQHBoxLayout)
        self.show()


if QtGui.QApplication.instance() is not None:
    myQApplication=QtGui.QApplication.instance()
else: 
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


myQTestWidget = QCustomWidget()
myQTestWidget.show()
myQApplication.exec_()
```

The problem here is, that this is all executed inside the QCustomLabel Class, and inside the MouseMoveEvent function. But I want a seperate function, lets call it `drawCircle`, outside of that class, which has access to the mouse position and events. With opencv this would be no problem at all. And it would take only a fraction of the writing effort, which is needed for a pyqt implementation.

I think the right question is: Why dont I like pyqt yet?

Comment: You're using PySide, not PyQt. But either way, it's always a mistake to try to force one language/library/framework to behave exactly like another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event-filter to avoid having to subclass the `QLabel`:

```
class QCustomWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowOpacity(1)
        # Init QLabel
        self.positionQLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.positionQLabel.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.positionQLabel.installEventFilter(self)
        # Init QLayout
        layoutQHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layoutQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.positionQLabel)    
        self.setLayout(layoutQHBoxLayout)
        self.show()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            self.drawCircle(event.x(), event.y())
        return super(QCustomWidget, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def drawCircle(self, x, y):
        # whatever
```

Comment: thank you very much. as far as i know, opencvs gui features build on qt. therefore it seemed natural to me, to derive a similar implementation in both frameworks.

Comment: @AntonAlice. I'm sure there's a lot of overlap, but obviously some things are going to work differently. I think you will find that qt offers you lots of flexibilty, but sometimes that comes at the cost of more a verbose implementation.

Comment: you forgot a Q in front of the QtGui._Label(self)

Comment: @ekhumoro.there is still a problem. As opposed to opencvs mouse callback, there is no seperate thread, which is updating event. event is only going to be updated each time eventFilter is called. What if drawCircles contains a while loop, which is waiting for a MouseButton release? It is going to loop forever, since the script never gets back to the event filter. 
 
I think it would be sufficient If one can manually update event each time one is inside the while loop. Is it a good way to simply insert a QtGui.QApplication.processEvents() inside the while loop?

Comment: @AntonAlice. Well, if you want a separate thread, then use a separate thread :-) Just don't try to do any gui operations outside of the main thread. You can create a `QImage` in the worker thread (but not a `QPixmap`), then send it to the gui using a custom signal.

Comment: @AntonAlice. Actually, on re-reading your comment, is a separate thread even needed? It seems all you'd need to do is set a flag on mouse-release that the while-loop can check to see if it needs to break.